# Не могу перейти на новое Activity

Tags: java, android

Не получается перейти на другое Activity.
У меня есть ImageView с обработчиком нажатия.

```
private void initButton() {
    ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(button);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Код первого Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

    initBackground();
    initButton();
    initBackButton();
    initHomeButton();
}
private void initBackground() {
    ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.background)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(background);
}
private void initButton() {
    ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(button);
}




private void initBackButton() {
    ImageView back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBackToCategories);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.arrow_back)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(back_button);
}

private void initHomeButton() {
    ImageView home_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBackToHome);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.home_button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(home_button);
}

public void onBackClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, CategoriesActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onHomeClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Код второго Activity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);

    initBackground();
    initButton();
    initBackButton();
    initHomeButton();

}
private void initBackground() {
    ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.background)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(background);
}
private void initButton() {
    ImageView skeleton_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.skeleton_button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(skeleton_button);
}




private void initBackToButton() {
    ImageView back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBackTo);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.arrow_back)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(back_button);
}

private void initHomeButton() {
    ImageView home_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBackToHome);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.home_button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(home_button);
}

public void onBackClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onHomeClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onClickSkeleton(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Выдает такую ошибку:

> 08-11 10:13:11.809 26573-26573/com.levqo.project E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.levqo.project, PID: 26573
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.levqo.project/com.levqo.project.Activity2}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null
>   View    at
>   com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.BitmapRequestBuilder.into(BitmapRequestBuilder.java:498)
>   at com.levqo.project.Activity2.initButton(Activity2.java:40)    at
>   com.levqo.project.Activity2.onCreate(Activity2.java:20)    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Что делать?

Comment: покажите код ваших активити

Comment: Возможно библиотека которую вы используете для загрузки изображений ругается. Проверьте все вьюхи не равнили они null перед там как передавать их в библиотеку.  начните с вот этой кнопки ImageView skeleton_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn);

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.levqo.project/com.levqo.project.Activity2}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View

Здесь говориться что вы не можете начать ComponentInfo который находится по адресу com.levqo.project/com.levqo.project.Activity2. Вы где то что-то неправильно объявили, ошибка банальная проверьте все ещё раз.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не заметил что ошибка в initButton. Pardon.

Comment: У вас в лайауте activity2 нет кнопки btn

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вы не добавили описание активити (`Activity2`) в файл манифеста (AndroidManifest.xml).

Например:

```
 <activity android:name="name_of_package.Activity2" android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Comment: У меня всё добавлено.

Comment: На всякий случай, добавьте содержимое вашего файла AndroidManifest.xml в пост?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще если читать вашу ошибку дословно то она говорит о том что активити у вас null. Можно содержимое файла activity2.xml и структуру проекта посмотреть? Просто сделайте принтскрин экран с раскрытой структурой проекта и что бы был видин листинг xml файла

Answer (score 0):

Glide Вам говорит, что метод into(View view) не может принимать null.

Кусок кода (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnBackTo) возращает null, т.к. на xml R.layout.activity2 нет ImageView c id = R.id.btn.